# Brunch: separating vendor and app javascript

Tags: javascript, build, require, brunch

I have made two bundles of javascript from our project- vendor and app. I do this in the manner suggested by the [documentation](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-), as seen in this snippet from my brunch-config.js:

```
files: {
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'js/vendor.js': /^(?!source\/)/,
      'js/app.js': /^source\//
    },
    entryPoints: {
      'source/scripts/app.jsx': 'js/app.js'
    }
  }
}
```

And I end up with a vendor.js and an app.js. But check out the file sizes:[image: files view]

Note how app.js is larger than vendor.js! This large size makes watching slower than it needs to be. Upon inspecting the contents of app.js, it seemed to contain lodash, React, and other libraries, which I expected it to get from vendor.js. And vendor.js seems to contain the same libraries, which I do expect.

My question: **Why are the libraries present in app.js? Why does app.js not reference them from vendor.js?**

It is possible I missing some piece of configuration. Here is my full brunch-config.js for your examination:

```
module.exports = {

  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'js/vendor.js': /^(?!source\/)/,
        'js/app.js': /^source\//
      },
      entryPoints: {
        'source/scripts/app.jsx': 'js/app.js'
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {joinTo: 'css/core.css'},
  },

  paths: {
    watched: ['source']
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      'js/app.js': ['source/scripts/app']
    }
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {presets: ['latest', 'react']},
    assetsmanager: {
      copyTo: {
        'assets': ['source/resources/*']
      }
    },
    static: {
      processors: [
        require('html-brunch-static')({
          processors: [
            require('pug-brunch-static')({
              fileMatch: 'source/views/home.pug',
              fileTransform: (filename) => {
                filename = filename.replace(/\.pug$/, '.html');
                filename = filename.replace('views/', '');
                return filename;
              }
            })
          ]
        })
      ]
    }
  },

  server: {
    run: true,
    port: 9005
  }

};
```

and in HTML I require these files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" defer></script>
```

I tried setting the order object, but to no avail:

```
files:
  javascripts: {
    joinTo: {
      'js/vendor.js': /^(?!source\/)/,
      'js/app.js': /^source\//
    },
    entryPoints: {
      'source/scripts/app.jsx': 'js/app.js'
    },
    order: {
      before: /^(?!source)/,
      after: /^source\//
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "assetsmanager-brunch": "^1.8.1",
    "babel-brunch": "^6.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "^1.0.0-rc-5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.10.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.11.6",
    "browser-sync-brunch": "^0.0.9",
    "brunch": "^2.10.9",
    "brunch-static": "^1.2.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "es6-promise": "^3.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "html-brunch-static": "^1.3.2",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "mocha": "^3.0.0",
    "nib": "^1.1.0",
    "nock": "^8.0.0",
    "oboe": "~2.1.2",
    "paper": "0.9.25",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta10",
    "pug-brunch-static": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "reselect": "^2.5.3",
    "spectrum-colorpicker": "~1.8.0",
    "stylus-brunch": "^2.10.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^2.10.0",
    "unibabel": "~2.1.0",
    "when": "~3.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "postal": "^2.0.5",
    "rc-tree": "^1.3.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  }
}
```

Another thought, could this have to do with using `require` instead of `import`?

If there's any other information I can provide that would be helpful please let me know. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE

Here's my folder structure, simplified:

```
node_modules
source
|---resources
|---scripts
|---styles
|---views
```

Here's the output structure produced by `brunch build`:

```
assets
css
|---core.css
js
|---app.js
|---app.js.map
|---vendor.js
|---vendor.js.map
home.html
```

Debug it for yourself! MVCE available. Follow these instructions:

1. Clone this [example repository](https://github.com/sehcheese/brunch-build-mvce)
2. `npm install`
3. `brunch build` (make sure it is installed globally with `npm install brunch -g`)
4. Compare the sizes of `app.js` and `vendor.js` in `public/js`. They should be 744 KB and 737 KB respectively. Examine the contents of app.js and note the library stuff. How is my `files.javascripts.joinTo['js/app.js']` including this with regex `/^source\//`?

Comment: What is your folder structure? Maybe you have to adjust the `conventions` to ignore your libraries: http://brunch.io/docs/config#-conventions-

Comment: @JohannesFilter Thanks for the link. I updated the question with my folder structure. `conventions` is supposed to ignore the node_modules folder from what I see in the [brunch source](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/lib/utils/config-validate.js#L75). I'll work on an MVCE.

Comment: @JohannesFilter I included a link to a repository that is an MVCE. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the mixture of `joinTo` and `entryPoints`.  I assume that with your config, you first split your code in `app.js` and `vendor.js` but then the `app.js` gets overridden by the output of the `entryPoints`.

In order to solve it, you have to choose one of the options:

**Option 1**

Remove the `entryPoints` declaration. This will just split your code along the provided RegEx.

**Option 2**

Remove the `joinTo` declaration and change the `entryPoints` to:

```
    entryPoints: {
      'source/scripts/app.jsx': {
        'js/vendor.js': /^(?!source\/)/,
        'js/app.js': /^source\//
      },
    }
```

**Conclusion**

In this very case, the output of both options is the same. But with `entryPoints` the code get's analyzed and only needed modules get bundled. Because there aren't any unnecessary modules, the size is the same. See [this issue](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1349) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't seem clear to me from the [documentation](http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-) that `entryPoints` and `joinTo` are mutually exclusive in practice, but that seems to be the case?

Comment: Yes, I also find the documentation a little bit misleading. I will try to update the documentation.

Comment: I ultimately settled on a configuration that used `joinTo` for libraries and `entryPoints` for my own code (so that it would be executed on load). I used `joinTo` for libraries so that using browser-sync-brunch would work, otherwise it wasn't being picked up. See the code sample in my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725754/brunch-source-mapping-not-hitting-breakpoints-in-chrome-devtools/43769123#43769123).