# Tree-shaking and externalize helpers in brunch

Tags: javascript, babeljs, brunch

I look at the output of my brunch/babel setup, and wonder if some things couldn't be optimized. Here is the `brunch-config.js` I will use as support for my questions:

```
module.exports = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/,
        'app.js': /^app/
      }
    }
  },
  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      'app.js': [ 'main.js' ] // my entry point
    }
  }
}
```

First, when using a module (using import/export), the whole is included even when things aren't used. For example, as a proof of concept, my `main.js` only includes this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

console.log('running')
```

My `vendor.js` then contains all the `vue` package content. I know there are tree-shaking possibilities in other bundlers (rollup does it well from scratch). I searched but couldn't find plugins in brunch for that.

My second point is about the code generated. I'm not sure if it comes from brunch or babel though. Both `vendor.js` and `app.js` contain the same tooling code to enable commonjs modules (aka require). Couldn't be that code only included in one bundle (let's say vendor)?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are looking for `entryPoints` instead of `joinTo`. Take it look at my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726576/brunch-separating-vendor-and-app-javascript/43747916#43747916

Comment: Yes entryPoints didn't appeared clear to me, like what you said in the comments of the other answer. I didn't realized path specs could be speficied, and I guess it will do the job.